# Change data type

Tags: sql, oracle

I created my table `Course_Section` with `CsectionID number(6) PRIMARY KEY`.
I would like to change `number(6)` by `number(2,2)` but can't figure it out.

I tried:

```
Alter table Course_section
Alter column CSectionID Number(2,2) PRIMARY KEY;
```

and get an error.

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry, my first time here. it's for Oracle sql database

Comment: Since it is the Primary Key I would rename the original and recreate the new with the new definition and then copy over the rows.  It is likely that this will reveal that your child and foreign keys also need to be updated.  My over simplistic explanation should not be used in a production environment.

Comment: So am I better dropping the table as there is nothing in it and recreate it with the right datatype?

Comment: TWO things.   (1)  If there are child tables also depenedent on that primary key then you need to know that and force those updates as well.   (2)  Since you are truly changing the type is why I recommend the full table build.    If it were not the primary key I would add a new field at the end of the table and then delete the existing field.  (not a rename per se)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off.  It should be:

```
ALTER TABLE Course_section
MODIFY CSectionID Number(2, 2);
```

Comment: Still not working, it's telling me it's missing a keyword.. :(

Comment: You need to remove the `primary key` part